# Convergence/divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac {\ln (n)} {\sqrt n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac {\ln (n)} {\sqrt n}$$

How can I determine/show whether the above series converges or diverges? It seems like I should use the Alternating Series Test, but I don't know how to find the limit as $n\to \infty$ of $A_n$, and I don't know if $A_n>A_{n+1}>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're letting $A_n={\ln n\over \sqrt n}$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=0$$
by L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: Oops, totally forgot about that- thanks! But, how do I show the $A_n$s are decreasing?

Comment: Show the derivative is negative after a certain point would probably be easiest.

Comment: But when I take the derivative of $A_n$, I get $\frac 2 {\sqrt n}$, which is always positive (except at $\infty$, where it's $0$). But I guess that kinda makes sense since that's what we got from L'Hospital's rule, so does that mean the second derivative in this case would actually be what we're looking for?

Comment: You've got that derivative wrong.  $f(x)=\ln x/\sqrt x, f'(x)=(2-\ln x)/(2x^{3/2})$.

Comment: Ah, thanks- I forgot about the quotient rule there

Answer (score 1):

There exists some famous covergence tests for conditional covergence ( not absolutly covergence ) . all of them are based on abel summation by part on series

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts and it is application in showing conditional covergence.